# Haskell using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

Hi I am new to Haskell and I am a little lost. I have been given this to do but can't work it out.

---

Using only `foldr`, the Boolean operation `(||)` and `False`, define a function

```
or_list :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

so that

```
or_list [b1, b2,...,bn] = b1 || b2 ||...|| bn
```

Note that

```
or_list [] = False
```

---

I come up with something like this

```
or_list :: [Bool] -> Bool
or_list [0..n] = foldr False (||) [0..n]
```

But don't really get how `foldr` works. If anyone could point me down the right road it would be a big help.

Comment: This isn't so much Haskell as it is just `fold` in general that you're asking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've almost got the definition right, but your syntax is a bit off.  You can't have a pattern match like

```
or_list [0..n] = ...
```

this just isn't valid syntax.  In fact, you don't need to pattern match at all, you could just do

```
or_list bs = foldr False (||) bs
```

The next problem can be revealed by looking at `foldr`'s type:

```
foldr :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> Bool -> [Bool] -> Bool
-- Simplified from its more general type
```

Notice that its first argument is a function that takes two boolean values, and the second argument is simply a boolean.  You have

```
foldr False (||) bs
```

But `False` isn't a function and `(||)` isn't a boolean.  If you swap them you'd get

```
foldr (||) False bs
```

And then your definition would be correct!

---

How does this work?  Folds are a generalization of a simple recursion, it's quite often that you have a function that you're applying to an argument that also depends on the last value computed.  These sorts of recursions are useful for turning a list of values into a single value.  The definition of `foldr` is pretty simple and I think it helps explain how the fold works

```
foldr f initial [] = initial
foldr f initial (x:xs) = f x (foldr f initial xs)
```

So if we were to plug in some values and expand it

```
  foldr (||) False [False, False, True]
= False || (foldr (||) False [False, True])
= False || (False || (foldr (||) False [True]))
= False || (False || (True || (foldr (||) False [])))
= False || (False || (True || (False)))
= False || (False || True)
= False || True
= True
```

Another way to look at it is that it replaces `:` by `f` and `[]` by `initial` in a list, so if you have

```
False : False : True : []
```

And you apply `foldr (||) False` to it, you would replace every `:` by `||` and the `[]` with `False`, associating right (the `r` part of `foldr`), so

```
False || (False || (True || (False)))
```

Which is the same as the expansion we got above.  A `foldl` works in the opposite association, so `foldl (||) False` looks like

```
(((False) || False) || False) || True
-- ^ initial
```

So the difference is basically what end the initial value gets stuck on and where the parenthesis are.

Answer (score 2):

The `foldr` function from the Prelude is a higher order function that takes a function `f` of type `(a -> b -> b)` and applies it to a list of type `[a]` resulting in a list of type `[b]`. It also takes a initial element `z` that is applied to the first application of `f`

Symbolically the reduction like this in pseudocode:

```
foldr f z [a,b,c,...,n] == f a (f b (f c (... (f n z)...)))
```

So for your function you need something like this:

```
foldr (||) False [a,b,c,...,n] = a || (b || (c ... (n || False)))
```

Hope that helps with intuition for foldr.

Answer (score 0):

You have the definition of:

```
or_list :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

right.

Lets look at the second line:

```
or_list [0..n] = foldr False (||) [0..n]
```

So actually this is pretty close to what is needed, but there are a couple problems. First of let's look at the:

```
or_list [0..n] = ...
```

This should instead be probably something like:

```
or_list (x:xs) = ...
```

Refer to [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) as to why. Next, I will give you some hints. Pay close attention to the signature of `foldr`, You're not quite giving the correct order of parameters. Also, you need to handle the case of an empty list `[]` which is actually mentioned in the link I gave you.